# What is the best way to get a linux ecosystem on my phone?

Tags: linux, terminal, android, productivity

I'm a programmer that uses the terminal for everything I do: VIM, git, pushing/getting files from the server and so on. Sometimes I'm on the street and for some reason I need to type a simple command - be it to restart my server, take a note or just ask a simple question on IRC - and, for that, I still need to wait til I access a computer. But I've been thinking, I have a 4G enabled powerful phone that is pretty much a pocket computer. Wouldn't it be great if I could just get it and use the terminal as I like?

In there any good way to get a full linux environment and terminal on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

On Android phones, if you root your phone, install [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en), and [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en), you will have a crippled but kind of functional Gnu/Linux environment.

However if you really want to be productive, you aren't going to get very much done locally. Android is just too odd and environment and the tools are too limited. What you should do is install an app like [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=en) and use it to remote into a server where you can do actual productive things.

For IRC check out one of the many, good and not so good IRC apps. Last time I checked [AndChat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.andchat&hl=en) was the least terrible.